# Error in web.xml file - Tomcat virtual server

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web.xml

I seem to be having a lot of problems with my web.xml file running on a virtual Tomcat server. Initially I had to convert the format to UTF-8, which solved a couple of errors but now I can't seem to make head or tail about this latest one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Error Log**

```
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.341 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;.
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.531 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.580 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.582 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.623 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.624 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 514 ms
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.648 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC5
05-Dec-2013 17:01:02.672 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\sample.war
05-Dec-2013 17:01:03.120 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
05-Dec-2013 17:01:03.246 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\helloworld
05-Dec-2013 17:01:03.260 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”ISO-8851-1” ?>
<web-app xmlns=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee”
xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xsi:schemaLocation=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd”
version=”2.4”>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>HWServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>test.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HWServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*this is the first part of the log file, if you think posting more would be helpful, I'll gladly post more.

Comment: Your web.xml is still broken. You should really use a IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse, their XML Editors make it easy to spot errors in XML.

Comment: The last line says `... Parse error in application web.xml ...`, like Gyro mentioned. Show us your `web.xml` file and we try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far guys. I've put up the web.xml file as you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you posted the entire `web.xml`? This isn't even valid XML: the `<servlet-mapping>` element isn't closed, the `<web-app>` element isn't closed, and you used the wrong quotes (`”` instead of `"`). So, for starters try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        metadata-complete="true"
        version="2.5"
        >
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HWServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HWServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you even read my answer? I said your `web.xml` had the wrong quotes - it still does. Try my sample and see if it helps. If you don't want to use an IDEs XML validator try one online e.g. http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did still try out your xml sample, but still no dice. I'm going to download an IDE and try out the xml validator as suggested above. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: "still no dice" is not the kind of information that help others help you solve the problem. There's certainly a _different kind_ of exception because the XML I provided is valid.